# Python Compare files using difflib showing incorrect result

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not able to get diff between the 2 files. If the content is ordered, then able to extract the diff. But if the content of the file is different between the 2 unable to get diff.

```
File A:
name:TEST1
type:localfile
filefull:True
filemonitored:True
fileziehigh:60
Destination:/tmp
flesizehigh:20
```

```
FIle B:
name:TEST1
type:localfile
description:
filefull:True
filemaxline:5000
filemonitored:True
fileziehigh:60
filelow:True
flesizehigh:20
monitor:True
folder:Root
folderowner:Root
```

```
 with open(FileA, 'r') as read_src:  
    with open(FileB,'r') as read_dst:
       diff = list(d.compare(read_src.read().splitlines(), read_dst.read().splitlines()))
 print(diff)
```

Trying to get the difference but unable to retrieve it.
Any guidance or better way to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine for me:

```py
import difflib

d = difflib.Differ()
with open('FileA', 'r') as read_src:  
    with open('FileB','r') as read_dst:
        diff = list(d.compare(read_src.read().splitlines(), read_dst.read().splitlines()))

print('\n'.join(diff))
```

which prints

```
  name:TEST1
  type:localfile
+ description:
  filefull:True
+ filemaxline:5000
  filemonitored:True
  fileziehigh:60
- Destination:/tmp
+ filelow:True
  flesizehigh:20
+ monitor:True
+ folder:Root
+ folderowner:Root
```

edit: This is the correct Myers diff of the two files. Is this not what you want the output to be?

Comment: Thanks @ATOMP but in my case it does not. I have the compare-file as a function and calling in it main by passign the file as param. Wold that be a problem.

Comment: No, that should work...as long as you're passing `open(...)` a string containing the path to your file.